# How to input a variable for the p id = "variable"

Tags: javascript, html, variables

I have the following code

```
<span id="X1a">

<script>

document.getElementById("X1").innerHTML = 'Output1'
document.getElementById("X2").innerHTML = 'Output2'

<!---etc - several more similar lines for Outputx-->


</script>
```

What I want to do is to be able to input (or select) the value to put in the id= line. So i can choose to print X1 or X2 or Xx. How can I do that?

Comment: When you say "be able to input" do you mean that you want the user to see a field where they can put a value? Then your code will take that value and display it on the page inside the span with `id="X1a"`? If so, your code needs a lot of work. I recommend taking a beginner JavaScript course so you can familiarize yourself with how Javascript interacts with form fields and inserts content on pages.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `setAttribute()` to change the value `id`.
example

```
document.getElementById("id").setAttribute("id", "X1")
```

or you can read reference in w3school

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp

Comment: I am most grateful for your speedy response. I have looked at the w3schools page and tried it but something seems to be wrong. I may not be doing it right. Could I trouble you to give me a hint. At the moment I open the source code and manually change <p id="X1"></p> to <p id="X2"></p>. What do I need to change that line to in order to either be able to input X2 (or any other value I choose), or press one of a series of buttons which have an option for X2, X3, X4 etc. Many thanks..